# haskell-problem: io string -> [int]

Tags: string, haskell, io, int

Hello great programmers out there,

I'm doing my first steps in haskell and have a function that confuses me:

```
import Data.List.Split
getncheck_guesslist = do
    line <- getLine
    let tmp = splitOneOf ",;" line
    map read tmp::[Int]
```

splitOneOf is in Data.List.Split (i installed it with cabal install split)
`splitOneOf :: (Eq a)=> [a]->[a]->[[a]]`

From the error I get it that there is some type incorrectness - but don't know how to solve this conflicts as *IO* is still a mystery to me

I want to read an input of integers separated by commas or semicolons and get a list of integers so:

- how can I check if user input is of type Int
- how can I "translate" the input which is of type "IO String" to [Int]

thank you in advance for thoughts and hints 
 - yours ε/2

Comment: If IO is a mystery you have two choices: either you unveil it by learning it, or you work without it and write functions without IO. I would suggest going with the second option for a while.

Answer (score 13):

When you're writing a function that uses the IO monad, any value you want to return from the function must also be in the IO monad.

This means that, instead of returning a value with type `[Int]`, you have to return something with type `IO [Int]`. To do this, you use the `return` function, which "wraps up" the value into `IO` (it actually works for *any* monad).

Just change the last line to wrap your value with `return`, like this:

```
getncheck_guesslist = do
    line <- getLine
    let tmp = splitOneOf ",;" line
    return (map read tmp :: [Int])
```

Answer (score 7):

The "right way" to do it in Haskell is to separate IO from, well, everything else. The direct translation of your code would be this:

```
getncheck_guesslist :: IO [Int]
getncheck_guesslist = do line <- getLine               -- get
                         return (check_guesslist line) -- check

check_guesslist :: String -> [Int]
check_guesslist line = let tmp = splitOneOf ",;" line
                       in map read tmp
```

Notice that `getncheck_guesslist` is simply an IO action. The function doesn't have input *parameters*, even though it does require *(IO) input* from `getLine`.

Also notice that `getncheck_guesslist` is a simple modification of the `getLine` IO action.  Isn't there a combinator that would let me push a function to act on the value inside a monad? Stop. Hoogle time!

I have a function `(a -> b)`. I have a value of the input type, but it's stuck in a monad `m a`. I want to perform the function inside the monad, so the result will inevitably be stuck in the monad too `m b`. Putting that all together, we hoogle [`(a -> b) -> m a -> m b`](http://haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=(a-%3Eb)+-%3E+m+a+-%3E+m+b). Lo and behold, `fmap` is just what we were looking for.

```
get_guesslist = check_guesslist `fmap` getLine
-- or, taking it a step further
get_guesslist = (map read . splitOneOf ",;") `fmap` getLine :: IO [Int]
```

As a final note, whenever you code a method with the name like `somethingAndSomethingElse`, it's usually better coding style to write and invoke `something` and `somethingElse` as two separate methods. For the final versions, I just renamed it `get_guesslist`, since conceptually that's what it does. It gets the guesses as a list of Ints.

As a final final note, I have left off at the point where barsoap started. ;) `fmap` is the same as `<$>`.

Answer (score 2):

If something is within the `IO` monad, you can't take it to the pure outside world for further processing. Instead, you pass your pure functions to work inside the functions within `IO`.

In the end, your program reads some input and writes some output, so your main function is going to work with `IO`, else you'll just not be able to output anything. Instead of reading `IO String` and creating an `[Int]`, pass the function that consumes that `[Int]` into your main function and use it inside `do`.

Answer (score 2):

```
import Data.List.Split
import Control.Applicative

getncheck_guesslist :: IO [Int]
getncheck_guesslist = map read . splitOneOf ",;" <$> getLine
```

Every time code bogs down to `foo >>= return . bar`, which yours does by desugaring the do-block (and correcting the type error), you are not using the monadic features of your monad, but only its functor part, that is, bluntly said, you are not messing with the `IO` part of the type, but with the `a` of `IO a`:

```
(<$>) :: (Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

(`fmap` would be the non-infix name for `<$>`. Both are closely related to `map`.)

That code above is pretty much idiomatic for ad-hoc code, but clean code would look like

```
import Data.Maybe

maybeRead :: Read a => String -> Maybe a
maybeRead = fmap fst . listToMaybe . reads 
                               -- That fmap is using "instance Functor Maybe"

parseGuessList :: String -> [Int]
parseGuessList =  catMaybes . map maybeRead . splitOneOf ",;"

getncheck_guesslist = parseGuessList <$> getLine
```

, or, alternatively, if you don't want to ignore non-int input but error out,

```
parseGuessList xs = if success then Just . catMaybes $ ys else Nothing 
  where ys :: String -> [Mabye Int]
        ys = map maybeRead . splitOneOf ",;" $ xs
        success = all isJust ys
```

(Beware, though, I have only proven that code correct, not actually tried it.)

If it gets any more complex than that you'd want to use a proper parsing library, I think.

Comment: This just went way over my head. I'm not going to downvote, but I have a feeling it went over the original poster's head as well.