# Convert Haskell IO list to list type

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [haskell-problem: io string -> [int]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090779/haskell-problem-io-string-int)

How I can convert Haskell IO list to normal list?

```
IO [value] -> [value]
```

Is there any built in function to do this?

Comment: How are you learning Haskell? There is no way to escape the monad (muhaha!). You can, however, unwrap it with `<-` in `do` notation, feed it to a pure function and do everything else with it, as long as you return an IO value at the end.

Comment: You can't without doing really dirty things. This question seems to come up every week or so, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090779/haskell-problem-io-string-int

Comment: If such a function existed, you could use it to crash your programs.  Haskell's semantics are supposed to prevent that, which is why all such functions are marked as "unsafe".

Comment: You can, but this is almost certainly the wrong way of solving your underlying problem. What is your underlying problem? Why do you want a `IO [value] -> [value]`?

Comment: thanxx all for your valuable replys, I get the data from db and I want to pass those values as normal haskell list,But i couldn't do that,because of the function type.So What I'm doing here is pass values to another function and try to get the data from dirty sql out put

Comment: 123Ex, you should add such extra information that you just gave to the question. You can edit your question and do that, maybe even add some code snippets.

Answer (score 11):

There are ways of doing what you ask for, but it is unsafe. Therefore, I think you should be looking at the problem the other way around. In staid of getting the list out of `IO`, you should lift your pure function into `IO`.

Let's say you wanted to get the list from DB and apply some pure function to it, then you could do the following:

```
yourFunc = do
  list <- getListFromDB
  return (myPureFunction List)
```

or if you want to print the result afterwords:

```
yourFunc = do
  list <- getListFromDB
  print (myPureFunction List)
```

In general, in order to calculate a pure
result inside of the IO monad you can use let:

```
yourFunc = do
  list <- getListFromDB
  let result = myPureFunction list
  return result
```

or more compact:

```
import Control.Monad((=<<))
import Control.Applicative((<$>))

yourFunc = print =<< myPureFunction <$> getListFromDB
```

Comment: Why is [sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) unsafe? (This is a genuine question)

Comment: @AntoineCatton Sequence is not unsafe, note that its type is (when using the `IO` monad) `[IO a] -> IO [a]`. What the question was asking for was something of type `IO [a] -> [a]`, which you can do with `unsafePerformIO`. However, if the `IO` operation has any side effects the outcome will be unpredictable.