# How do I convert a IO [[Int]] to [[Int]] in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Haskell IO list to list type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802331/convert-haskell-io-list-to-list-type)

I've tried searching but didn't seem to find a proper answer, is this possible in the first place? Any help in this is appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

This isn't possible. An `IO [[Int]]` doesn't *contain* an `[[Int]]`; it is a description of an imperative program that does IO which, when executed, will produce a result of type `[[Int]]`. Such a description could never be executed at all, or executed any number of times (to produce an `[[Int]]` each time, and not necessarily the same one).

Haskell is a pure language, so there is no way to execute an `IO` description directly; instead, you can compose them into larger descriptions. To cause IO to actually happen, you can define `main` to be an `IO` action, which is then executed when the program runs; or you can enter `IO` actions (like `putStrLn "Hello, world!"`) into GHCi, which will run them.

The simplest way to compose `IO` actions is with `do` notation, which you've probably already used. Here's an example:

```
myAction :: IO [[Int]]
myAction = ...

main :: IO ()
main = do
    xs <- myAction
    -- now xs is a normal value with type [[Int]]
    print xs
```

See [this FAQ](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FAQ#How_do_I_convert_IO_Int_to_Int.3F) and the [introduction to IO](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_IO) for more information.

Comment: Ah, nice, you expanded your answer and thereby made my answer mostly redundant :-)

Answer (score 9):

The answer by ehird is correct — a value of type `IO [[Int]]` is a description of how to get a list of lists of integers. This is also called an *action*.

To get the `[[Int]]` you need to *perform* the action. You can do with the `<-` operator in `do` notation. That gives you the result of performing the action and you can then operate on this value as needed. You still need to put the value back into the IO monad sooner or later, though. In concrete code it can look like this:

```
sumAll :: IO [[Int]] -> IO Int
sumAll io_lists = do
  lists <- io_lists
  return $ sum $ map sum lists
```

Here, `lists` is bound to the result of performing the IO action. You can therefore map `sum` over it with no problem. The `return` function from the IO monad puts the valube "back" into the monad so that the return type becomes `IO Int`. Some monads lets you take values out of the monad, but IO doesn't — it represents side effects and you cannot remove a side effect from your code.